# Relational Algebra: Finding duplicates in a specific attribute of a relation

Tags: logic, relation-algebra

I have a relation $PC$, defined as:

$$\textbf{PC} = \matrix{model & speed & ram & hd & price \cr
                        1001 & 2.66 & 1024 & 250 & 2114 \cr
                        1002 & 2.62 & 1024 & 300 & 800 \cr
                        1003 & 3.24 & 2048 & 250 & 2570 \cr
                        1004 & 3.11 & 4096 & 100 & 1100 \cr
                        1005 & 3.20 & 2048 & 80 & 2400 \cr
                        1006 & 3.00 & 2048 & 100 & 2570 \cr}$$

I want to isolate $hd$'s that have sizes that exist more than once -- i.e. duplicates. How can I do this using operators such as projection ( $\pi$ )?

So far, I've thought of doing a procedure such as this:

$$A := \pi_{hd}(PC)$$
$$B := \pi_{hd}(PC)$$
$$\pi_{A}(\sigma_{A=B} (A \times B)) - \pi_{hd}(PC)$$

Which I'm hoping would give me the column:

$$\matrix{hd \cr
                        250 \cr
                        100 \cr}$$

But I know that projection removes duplicates so I doubt this is right.

Can Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Think about the $\div$ because it means "for all"